# how to write basic jquery if statement based on url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know why this doesnt work. Although im sure its something to do with the way im handling the url in the if statement. My Jquery / javascript knowledge if basic.

```
var url = $(location).attr('href');

if (url == 'http://www.website.com/test/index.html')
{
  $('#HomeButton').bind('click', HomeButton);
} 

function HomeButton(e) {
e.preventDefault();

doSomething....

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use jquery to access standard object properties.

You can do

```
if (document.location.href == 'http://www.website.com/test/index.html')
```

but you should never compare to the whole URL : you'd have wrong result if you change your domain, test elsewhere, use https, add a parameter, etc. You should use the intended property of `location`, that is `pathname` :

```
if (document.location.pathname == '/test/index.html')
```

In case of doubt, if you want to be sure of your pathname, simply open Chrome's developer tools (by typing F12) and type this on the console : `document.location.pathname`.

Comment: You can also just use the click() method instead of binding to a function... `$('#HomeButton').click(function(){ //do stuff });`

Comment: @Conner actually, canonical jQuery is now `.on('click', ...)`

Comment: Ok then `.on('click', function(e) { //do stuff });`

Comment: im actually having trouble with the if check...
so this works:
    if (window.location.href === 'http://website.com/test/index.html')

but only if someone navigates using no www in the address...If someone does, the function wont work.

is there a way to say: if (window.location.href === 'http://website.com/test/index.html' and 'http://www.website.com/test/index.html')
????

Comment: for some reason in my example above the comment is only showing website.com/test when, on the last link shown, it should have a www infront of it. So basically i was asking if there was a way to account for both urls in the IF statement? Both URLS being website.com and website.com with a www infront of it

Comment: Yes : use `pathname`, not `href`. See answer.

Comment: your right that totally works. thanks again - thanks for the consol debug script, thats really cool, didnt even know you could write in the consol that way!

Answer (score 1):

`window.location` isn't a a DOM element so you can't use jQuery methods on it.

The `.href` is actually a *property* of a `Location` object.

Just use it direct - `if (window.location.href === ...)`